# Sqlite - Get Cell Column Order With Cell Content

Tags: c#, sqlite, cell, rank

i have been making my internship on a project, which saving runners target access time (TAT) and i am trying to get some valuable results from these times.

Example:

How much time have runners spend between targets? (Target Time - TT)

What is the rank of runner at TAT?

Also need rank of runner at target time but now TAT is important.

I prepared some html tables for explain myself;

Here what i have. I saved this query result as view now i have been working on this view for a while (View name is "RunnerTimes").

```html
RunnerTimes (Sqlite View)
<table width="600" height="164" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="48" height="38">Name</td>
    <td width="159">Target 1 AccessTime</td>
    <td width="159">Target 2 AccessTime</td>
    <td width="169">Target 3 AccessTime</td>
    <td width="172">Target 4 AccessTime</td>
    <td width="157">Target 5 AccessTime</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="37">John</td>
    <td>13:06:00</td>
    <td>13:25:00</td>
    <td>13:32:00</td>
    <td>13:42:00</td>
    <td>13:53:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="38">Alice </td>
    <td>13:07:00</td>
    <td>13:22:00</td>
    <td>13:34:00</td>
    <td>13:44:00</td>
    <td>13:56:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="39">Mark</td>
    <td>13:05:00</td>
    <td>13:27:00</td>
    <td>13:34:00</td>
    <td>13:41:00</td>
    <td>13:54:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But my supervisor needs something more complicated table.

```html
Supervisor needs table like that
<table width="600" height="342" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="48">Name</td>
    <td width="159">Target 1 AccessTime</td>
    <td width="159">Target 2 AccessTime</td>
    <td width="169">Target 3 AccessTime</td>
    <td width="172">Target 4 AccessTime</td>
    <td width="157">Target 5 AccessTime</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#FFCC66">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>13:06:00 (2)</td>
    <td>13:25:00 (2)</td>
    <td>13:32:00 (1)</td>
    <td>13:42:00 (2)</td>
    <td>13:53:00 (1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="51">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td> <p>time = 00:19:00 <br>
      time = target2 - target1</p></td>
    <td>00:07:00</td>
    <td>00:06:00</td>
    <td>00:11:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#FFCC66">
    <td>Alice </td>
    <td>13:07:00 (3)</td>
    <td>13:22:00 (1)</td>
    <td>13:34:00 (2)</td>
    <td>13:44:00 (3)</td>
    <td>13:56:00 (3)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td> 00:15:00</td>
    <td>00:12:00</td>
    <td>00:10:00</td>
    <td>00:12:00</td>
  </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="#FFCC66">
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>13:05:00 (1)</td>
    <td>13:27:00 (3)</td>
    <td>13:34:00 (3)</td>
    <td>13:41:00 (1)</td>
    <td>13:54:00 (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td> 00:22:00</td>
    <td>00:07:00</td>
    <td>00:07:00</td>
    <td>00:13:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I achieve this  ranks "(2)" or "(1)" like at this table.

I tried to do it by myself in C# but its ultraslow, calculating Target Times, querying runner ranks and after adding these to table is very slow.

Can some one help me? Sorry for bad english cheers :)

---

Edit

RunnerTimes - below sql gives me table of access times - IF there is no access writing 'mp' to cell

```html
"SELECT t.braceletID As 'Bracelet',(t.Name|| ' ' || t.Surname) As 'Runner',
IFNULL( MAX(CASE WHEN r.ControlID = 24 THEN time(julianday(strftime('%H:%M:%S',r.accesstime))-.5)END),'mp') AS '1',

IFNULL( MAX(CASE WHEN r.ControlID = 26 THEN time(julianday(strftime('%H:%M:%S',r.accesstime))-.5)END),'mp') AS '2',

IFNULL( MAX(CASE WHEN r.ControlID = 28 THEN time(julianday(strftime('%H:%M:%S',r.accesstime))-.5)END),'mp') AS '3',

IFNULL( MAX(CASE WHEN r.ControlID = 23 THEN time(julianday(strftime('%H:%M:%S',r.accesstime))-.5)END),'mp') AS '4',

IFNULL( MAX(CASE WHEN r.ControlID = 25 THEN time(julianday(strftime('%H:%M:%S',r.accesstime))-.5)END),'mp') AS '5'

FROM Runner t Left Outer Join RunnerAccess r On  t.braceletid = r.RunnerID 

Where t.categoryid=1  GROUP BY  t.braceletid"
```

Runners participate in category and targets are different for categories 
At this query targets are "24 - 26 - 28 - 23 - 25".
I changed column names and setted them to "1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5" then created RunnerTimes  view in SQLite.

Comment: Can you post the code behind it

Comment: Here i add my sqlite query